# How can I do a git svn reset to HEAD revision without specifying the revision number?

Tags: git-svn

How can I do a git svn reset to HEAD revision without specifying the revision number?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? git svn reset is rarely needed, and if you need it, you should know what revision number you want to do it for

Comment: so how do i go back to head? i need it because i reverted to an older revision to test something out. and now i wanna skip back to HEAD.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want is not a `git svn reset` but a simple `git checkout`. I'm not sure what you mean when you say you reverted to an older revision, but it may have been something like

```
$ git log
# scan through the log looking for a particular commit.
# You find it and its SHA1 is abc123...
$ git checkout abc123
You are now in 'detached HEAD' state blah blah blah...
```

Now, HEAD (in your git repository) refers to the commit with SHA1 abc123, whereas HEAD (in the central SVN repository) refers to the newest commit on the SVN repository. If you have things set up in a fairly typical way, then you can just do `git checkout master` and then `git svn rebase` and you're back to normal working conditions.